# Графический разбор слова

Tags: русская-графика

Правильно ли выполнен:

Село [с`ило]. 4 буквы – 4 звука.
2. C – двузначная буква ([c], [c’]), звуковое значение [c’] устанавливается в графическом слоге се: буква е указывает на мягкость согласного, обозначенного предшествующей согласной буквой, т.е. действует слоговой принцип русской графики. Буква е передаёт звук [и], звуковое значение – второстепенное; буква л («эл») передаёт звук [л], звуковое значение – главное?

Comment: А почему буква ЭЛЬ обделена (не как ЭС)? Разве она не двузначная ([л|л'])? И разве буква О не указывает на твёрдость предшествующего согласного?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё верно. А "О" разве не нужно, если оно в сильной позиции?

Answer (score 0):

1. Село′ [с’иэ л о′] <с’э л о>
2. Буква с («эс») передаёт звук [с’], звуковое значение – главное; буква е передаёт звук [иэ], звуковое значение – второстепенное; буква л («эл») передаёт звук [л], звуковое значение – главное; буква о передаёт звук [о], звуковое значение главное.
3. C – двузначная буква ([c], [c’]), звуковое значение [c’] устанавливается в графическом слоге се: буква е указывает на мягкость согласного, обозначенного предшествующей согласной буквой, т.е. действует слоговой принцип русской графики.
   Е – двузначная буква ([э], [jэ]), звуковое значение не устанавливается в графическом слоге, а объясняется фонетической позицией гласного –  [иэ]: первый предударный слог, после мягкого согласного.
   Л – двузначная буква ([л], [л’]), звуковое значение [л] устанавливается в графическом слоге ло: буква о указывает на мягкость согласного, обозначенного предшествующей согласной буквой, т.е. действует слоговой принцип русской графики.
   О – однозначная буква ([о]), звуковое значение не устанавливается в графическом слоге, а объясняется фонетической позицией гласного –  [о]: ударный слог.